# in c++ main function is the entry point to program how i can change it to an other function?

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

I was asked an interview question to change the entry point of a C or C++ program from `main()` to any other function. How is it possible?

Comment: You don't. It has to either be `main`, or some implementation-defined entry point. There's no standard way.

Comment: Depends on your compiler/linker.

Comment: The entry point of a program is where it starts executing at the machine code level. That's seldom if ever `main`; instead, the entry point function does a few initialization tasks and then, for a C or C++ program, calls `main`. So the question does not make sense. Are you sure that that was the exact question?

Comment: Not a good interview question. The best answer will be "I Don't Know".

Comment: My answer (though it may not get me the job) would be "Can I get a bit of whatever you were smoking when you thought up that question?" :-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In standard C (and, I believe, C++ as well), you can't, at least not for a hosted environment (but see below). The standard specifies that the starting point for the C code is `main`. The standard (c99) doesn't leave much scope for argument:

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup: (1) The function called at program startup is named main.

That's it. It then waffles on a bit about parameters and return values but there's really no leeway there for changing the name.

That's for a hosted environment. The standard also allows for a freestanding environment (i.e., no OS, for things like embedded systems). For a freestanding environment:

> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. Any library facilities available to a freestanding program, other than the minimal set required by clause 4, are implementation-defined.

You can use "trickery" in C *implementations* so that you can make it look like `main` isn't the entry point. This is in fact what early Windows compliers did to mark `WinMain` as the start point.

---

First way: a linker may include some pre-main startup code in a file like `start.o` and it is this piece of code which runs to set up the C environment then call `main`. There's nothing to stop you replacing that with something that calls `bob` instead.

---

Second way: some linkers provide that very option with a command-line switch so that you can change it without recompiling the startup code.

---

Third way: you can link with this piece of code:

```
int main (int c, char *v[]) { return bob (c, v); }
```

and then your entry point for *your* code is seemingly `bob` rather than `main`.

---

However, all this, while of possibly academic interest, doesn't change the fact that I can't think of one single solitary situation in my many decades of cutting code, where this would be either necessary or desirable.

I would be asking the interviewer: why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: +1 for making `main` just call something else. That's the most straightforward and cross-platform method to accomplish this.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do some implementation defined hackery with the constructors of global objects? Demons flying out your nose on other platforms guaranteed, of course.

Comment: @paxdiablo How about a static block?

Answer (score 13):

The entry point is actually the `_start` function (implemented in *crt1.o*) .

The `_start` function prepares the command line arguments and then calls `main(int argc,char* argv[], char* env[])`, 
you can change the entry point from `_start` to `mystart` by setting a linker parameter:

```
g++ file.o -Wl,-emystart -o runme
```

Of course, this is a replacement for the entry point `_start` so you won't get the command line arguments:

```
void mystart(){

}
```

Note that global/static variables that have constructors or destructors must be initialized at the beginning of the application and destroyed at the end. Keep that in mind if you are planning on bypassing the default entry point which does it automatically.

Comment: this did not work

Answer (score 12):

From C++ standard docs *3.6.1 Main Function*,

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. **It is implementation-defined**
>   whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function.

So, it **does depend** on your compiler/linker...

Comment: That's interesting. There's no indication in cpp0x that the first sentence there applies only to hosted, and `shall` is normally a standards word that means it _must_ be so. So it appears that `main` must exist even for freestanding. Can someone with more C++-Standard-fu than me figure that out? Can you _have_ a `main` without being required to define it??

Comment: Actually that appears to be the case for C as well. I was looking at the hosted section. The freestanding section is a bit looser with the requirements. +1.

Comment: @paxdiablo:  I think the intent is that the second sentence qualifies the first sentence, so that it means "A program [in a hosted environment] shall contain..."  I think "shall contain" means "shall contain [a definition of];" I don't know how else the word "contain" could be understood.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I did refer from N2461 draft one.. Haven't updated to the recent though.. Am I making a mistake over here??

Comment: No, I don't think you're making a mistake here, liaK, there's similar language in C99.

Comment: @James, I think you're probably right in that it applies only to hosted (again because C99 makes a big distinction as well). I don't know what environment ISO were thinking of when they relaxed the rules that much. Even in the _tiniest_ embedded systems I worked on, there was still startup code and a `main` :-)

Comment: Uhm, it provides a cop-out for the Microsoft toolchain, which by default does not accept a standard `main` for a GUI subsystem program. Perhaps this was what the interviewer were asking about. But in that case it's not about specifying a different startup function (called "entry point" by folks here), but instead about specifying the standard startup function, MS linker option `entry:mainCRTStartup` (lest the MS linker complain about a missing `WinMain` :-) ). Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 7):

If you are on VS2010, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) could give you some idea

As it is easy to understand, this is not mandated by the C++ standard and falls in the domain of 'implemenation specific behavior'.

Answer (score 4):

This is highly speculative, but you might have a static initializer instead of main:

```
#include <iostream>

int mymain()
{
    std::cout << "mymain";
    exit(0);
}

static int sRetVal = mymain();

int main()
{
    std::cout << "never get here";
}
```

You might even make it 'Java-like', by putting the stuff in a constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyApplication
{
public:
    MyApplication()
    {
        std::cout << "mymain";
        exit(0);
    }
};

static MyApplication sMyApplication;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "never get here";
}
```

Now. The interviewer might have thought about these, but I'd personally never use them. The reasons are:

- It's non-conventional. People won't understand it, it's nontrivial to find the entry point.
- Static initialization order is nondeterministic. Put in another static variable and you'll never now if it gets initialized.

That said, I've seen it being used in production instead of `init()` for library initializers. The caveat is, on windows, (from experience) your statics in a DLL might or might not get initialized based on usage.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the crt object that actually calls the `main()` function, or provide your own (don't forget to disable linking of the normal one).

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

With gcc, declare the function with attribute((constructor)) and gcc will execute this function before any other code including main.

Answer (score 2):

For Solaris Based Systems I have found [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Solaris-Pragmas.html). You can use the `.init` section for every platforms I guess:

```
   pragma init (function [, function]...)
```

Source:

> This pragma causes each listed function to be called during initialization (before main) or during shared module loading, by adding a call to the .init section.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

As you should know when you use constants in c, the compiler execute a kind of 'macro' changing the name of the constant for the respective value.

just include a `#define` argument in the beginning of your code with the name of start-up function followed by the name `main`:

Example:

```
#define my_start-up_function (main)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easy to remove the undesired main() symbol from the object before linking.

Unfortunately the entry point option for g++ is not working for me(the binary crashes before entering the entry point). So I strip undesired entry-point from  object file.

Suppose we have two sources that contain entry point function.

1. target.c contains the main() we do not want.
2. our_code.c contains the testmain() we want to be the entry point.

After compiling(g++ -c option) we can get the following object files.

1. target.o, that contains the main() we do not want.
2. our_code.o that contains the testmain() we want to be the entry point.

So we can use the objcopy to strip undesired main() function.

> objcopy --strip-symbol=main target.o

We can redefine testmain() to main() using objcopy too.

> objcopy --redefine-sym testmain=main our_code.o

And then we can link both of them into binary.

> g++ target.o our_code.o -o our_binary.bin

This works for me. Now when we run `our_binary.bin` the entry point is `our_code.o:main()` symbol which refers to `our_code.c::testmain()` function.

Answer (score 1):

On windows there is another (rather unorthodox) way to change the entry point of a program: `TLS`. See this for more explanations: http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=6655

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
We can change the main function name to any other name for eg. Start, bob, rem etc.

How does the compiler knows that it has to search for the main() in the entire code ?

Nothing is automatic in programming.
somebody has done some work to make it looks automatic for us.

so it has been defined in the start up file that the compiler should search for main().

we can change the name main to anything else eg. Bob and then the compiler will be searching for Bob() only.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a value in Linker Settings will override the entry point. i.e., MFC applications use a value of 'Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)' to change entry point from main() to CWinApp::WinMain().

```
Right clicking on solution > Properties > Linker > System > Subsystem > Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)
```

...

Very practical benefit to modifying entry point:

MFC is a framework we take advantage of to write Windows applications in C++. I know it's ancient, but my company maintains one for legacy reasons! You will not find a main() in MFC code. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akdx0603.aspx) says the entry point is WinMain(), instead. Thus, you can override the WinMain() of your base CWinApp object. Or, most people override CWinApp::InitInstance() because the base WinMain() will call it.

Disclaimer: I use empty parentheses to denote a method, without caring how many arguments.