# When do C programs not have main function

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, program-entry-point

I am going through couple of VS solutions. The c files belonging to the project do not have main function, they do have functions like MainWindProc and several others.

Are VS soln files significantly different in the sense that their main function is declared somewhere else e.g. in .sln file rather than in.c file?

Comment: They don't have `main()` when 1. they're libraries (not this case), or 2. they're non-standard crap (this is the case).

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not usually one to defend MS, but that's unfair. VS supports programs with `main`, but it also provides applications library environments that supply `main` together with a large set of libraries. That's no more "non-standard crap" than using GTK or QT. (OTOH, VS does not and never will support C99, and that *is* crappy.)

Comment: @JimBalter Yeah, quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as every C application and C++ application must have a **main** function as its starting point, **every Win32-based application must have a WinMain** function.

Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here,MainWindProc is your entry point. We can change entry point of a c programme by using one of the mettod described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974796/in-c-main-function-is-the-entry-point-to-program-how-i-can-change-it-to-an-oth)