# Is it possible to call a function without calling main function?

Tags: c

If we need to call any function we need to call it from main or from the function inside main in nested way. Program starts always from main function.

```
//fun1.c
fun1(void){
/*Do something useful*/
return 0;
}

//main_fun.c
main(void){
fun1();
return 0;
}
```

what if we don't want to use main function and want to directly call fun1.
Is that possible to directly pointing the program counter to fun1 address so that it will start from there?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please don't do really strange things, for little or no reason... If you don't want to call your function, then don't. Comment it out. Or don't link main.c. Or use `#ifdef` compiler switches.

Comment: seems to be very similar to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974796/in-c-main-function-is-the-entry-point-to-program-how-i-can-change-it-to-an-oth

Comment: i don't want to but someone asked me that question in an interview .. so i was curious to know the answer. Sorry for that if u guys think that is a dumb question.. np :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and following [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) (see [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), its latest draft, which is actually the standard in practice) standards define two flavors of C implementations (see [C syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax) wikipage) .

- *hosted implementations* (useful to code application software, e.g. on Linux, POSIX, or probably Windows) give you a [standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (`libc`) - giving `malloc` from `<stdlib.h>` and `printf` from `<stdio.h>` etc etc..., and your program should define a `main` function (of signature `int main(int, char**)` or just `int main(void)`). In a hosted implemention most functions are indirectly called from `main`. As [John Zwinck answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838464/841108), some compilers give you a way to define functions to be called before `main` in a very implementation specific way (and order). Notice that the `libc` usually requires some implementation specific initialization and your `main` is actually called from [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) in an implementation specific way.
- *freestanding implementations* (useful to code system kernel software, or embedded software on micro-controllers) don't provide a full `libc` and do not define how the code can be run (and started). In that case your implementation should define how the software is run. In practice you'll need some external (e.g. assembly) code to call functions from your code.

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler accepts the `-ffreestanding` flag to give you a freestanding implementation (otherwise it is hosted)

Notice that hosted implementations are permitted to compile some standard functions in a tricky and magic way (if you `#include` the standard header defining them). See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816706/841108).

Notice also that the standard is defining how `main` works in a hosted implementation (*§5.1.2.2. Hosted environment* page 12 of `n1570`). In particular `main` is the only function where the lack of `return` is the same as `return 0;` (also the standard [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) function would end the program nearly as if returning from `main`).

In practice your question is implementation specific.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GCC or Clang you can use the `constructor` function attribute.

```
__attribute__((constructor))
fun1(void){
// ...
```

It's described in detail here: [How exactly does __attribute__((constructor)) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053029/how-exactly-does-attribute-constructor-work)