# Main function Concept in C

Tags: c

I am wondering if it is possible that Can you write two functions in which one function executes before main and the other function executes after main function??  This was asked in a quiz contest, and I am finding difficulty in searching the answer for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974796/in-c-main-function-is-the-entry-point-to-program-how-i-can-change-it-to-an-oth

Answer (score 3):

For running stuff at exit you can use [atexit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void we_are_dying()
{
       printf("Get the doctor!\n");

}

int main(void) {
    atexit(we_are_dying);
    // your code goes here
    printf("We are done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

For running stuff before main I do not think this is possible.

Comment: Well, you could hack the crt to call 'preMain()' before calling main(), but that seems as pointless as the OP's question is anyway.

Answer (score 0):

GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) compiler has added many extensions to C that were commonly overlooked. 
These added extensions can help us to simplify the development of C applications. One of the extension was addition of attributes. Based upon attribute specified, we can instruct the compiler to treat functions or variables specially.

Using the constructor attribute, we can specify the functions to be executed before and after the execution of `main()` function. Refer the example given below (Taken From - https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/c-program-callling-a-function-before-main/) .

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Apply the constructor attribute to startFunc() so that it
    is executed before main() */
void startFunc (void) __attribute__ ((constructor));

/* Apply the destructor attribute to lastFunc() so that it
   is executed after main() */
void lastFunc (void) __attribute__ ((destructor));

void startFunc (void)
{
    printf ("startup code before main()\n");
}

void lastFunc (void)
{
    printf ("Function after main()\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("In Main Function\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The link that i have mentioned above has shown another way to achieve the startup and exit functions. But `#pragma startup ..` `#pragma exit ...`  is not supported in gcc. 
In gcc and clang, you should use `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))` instead.