# How Do I run a certain .cpp file in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a project with several .cpp files that I want to run separately, for instance if I have A.cpp and B.cpp, visual studio is persistent on running A.cpp, but I want to run B.cpp. I have tried setting B.cpp as start up project but it doesn't change anything. Does anyone have any idea? Ihave the 2019 community version

Comment: It will run whatever file in the project has a main function. If you have more than one main, you need to put it in a separate project.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3974851/11261546) may help you, I think you could have done a bit more research before posting your question :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't run .cpp files. You compile them into executable files, and you run the executable file.

Comment: ***I have a project with several .cpp files that I want to run separately*** Visual Studio Community does not work this way. A project is a single executable or less (could be a library or structural / dependency target without code). You can have at most 1 `int main()` per project.

Comment: You can have a Visual Studio solution with multiple projects each building a single executable. Many of my own solutions usually have 20 or so projects between library targets, unit testing and utility executables and other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run certain functions in order to see if they're working properly, that is a good thing and is called Unit Testing.

You want to look into the C++ unit testing features of Visual Studio.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -1):

There are two methods that you could refer to:

1. Refer to Mocrosoft Docs about [Write unit tests for C/C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019)

2.Right click the .cpp->Select `Properties`->Set `Excluded From Build` to `Yes`

[image]