# C Program startup definition unclear

Tags: c, language-lawyer, definition, c11

below is what the C standard say about *Program startup* in C but i find the last part of the definition unclear:

**or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.**

i need to know what that exactly means any good references are appreciated

thanks in advance

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
> used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

> **or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974796/in-c-main-function-is-the-entry-point-to-program-how-i-can-change-it-to-an-oth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494244/how-to-change-entry-point-of-c-program-with-gcc

Comment: The “implementation” of C is the compiler and the other parts needed to build and execute programs, such as header files, software libraries, operating system, and computer hardware. “Implementation-defined” means the C implementation must document the choices it makes. The compiler and other parts of the C implementation should have a manual, and that manual should list what formats of declaration it supports for `main`. That is what it means for `main` to be declared in “some other implementation-defined manner.”

Comment: Also notably you are quoting the hosted implementation sub-chapter. In freestanding systems, the function called upon start-up is always implementation-defined.